# Is the quotient ring (R+A)/A equal to R/A?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals

I am studying the Second Isomorphism theorem.
Let $R$ be a subring of a ring $E$ and let $A$ be an ideal of $E$. There exists an isomorphism between the ring $(R+A)/A$ and $R/(A \cap R)$.

In my opinion, the quotient ring $(R+A)/A$ is equal to $R/A$, but why in the theorem is written the ring $(R+A)/A$ and not $R/A$? Does it mean that these two rings are not equal?

Would you help me, please? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot define $R/A$  if $A$ is not a subset (ideal) of $R$.